# Android FlashLight Application

Tags: java, android

I wrote an Android Flash Light application but that seems to show some strange behavior.

The code that is invoked on clicking the "Turn On" button is

```
public void flashLightOn(View view){
        try {
            if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH))
            cam = Camera.open(0);
            Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
            p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            cam.setParameters(p);
            cam.startPreview();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now , the strange thing is that this app works fine on some phones and doesn't work on others.

I have tried it on my OnePlus One and Motorola Droid Mini and on both of them it works fine, but when I ran it on a Motorola Droid RAZR and Moto E it didn't work.

I am not able to understand the problem here. Can anyone help?

Comment: "it didn't work" is not a good way to report problems. You need to post error messages for us to help.

Comment: Put in the catch-block 
Log.e("No Flash", "Error: "+e);

Comment: Are you getting NullPointerException. Am I right? The next time please post the logcat.

Comment: checkout my [post](https://acomputerengineer.wordpress.com/2013/09/12/turn-on-and-turn-off-flash-light-programmatically-in-android/) at my blog on how to turn on and turn off flash light properly

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with:

```
public void flashLightOn(View view){
        try {
            if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH))
{ // you don't added this
            cam = Camera.open(0);
            Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
            p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            cam.setParameters(p);
            cam.startPreview();
} // and this
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the difference between OPs code and this code?